# How can I add a float variable with a int variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables

I'm new at Java so I'm also working in some exercises. This one asks me to get a bill, get a interest, calculate the interest in that bill and then return the bill plus the interest.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BillsAndInterest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double bill;
        System.out.println("How mutch is the bill payment? ");
           bill = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("What's the interest in this bill in per cent?");
           double interest = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
        
        double interestCalculated = interest / 100 * bill;
           System.out.println("Your interest is " + interestCalculated + " dinheiros! \n So the amount is " + bill + interestCalculated + " dinheiros!");
    }
}
```

So the problem is, if my bill is 100 dinheiros and the interest is 25, then bill + interest must be 125, but the code returns **100.025.0 dinheiros!**

I've tried changing `double interestCalculated` to `int interestCalculated`, but I got this error:
*BillsAndInterest.java:15: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
int interestCalculated = interest / 100 * bill;
^
1 error*

Can someone please help me? Is there some specific class that I should look for help?

Comment: try with `(bill + interestCalculated)` instead of `bill + interestCalculated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code.

You only need to declare scanner class object once and your calculation is correct but while printing digit instead of `bill + interestCalculated` try with `(bill + interestCalculated)`

```
class BillsAndInterest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double bill;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How mutch is the bill payment? ");
        bill = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What's the interest in this bill in per cent?");
        double interest = scanner.nextDouble();

        double interestCalculated = interest / 100 * bill;
        System.out.println("Your interest is " + interestCalculated + " dinheiros! \n So the amount is " + (bill + interestCalculated) + " dinheiros!");
    }
}
```

### It's give me below O/P

```
How mutch is the bill payment? 
100
What's the interest in this bill in per cent?
25
Your interest is 25.0 dinheiros! 
 So the amount is 125.0 dinheiros!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one `Scanner`. The word is "much" (not "mutch"). You can declare and initialize variables with one statement. And the total of interest for 25% is `1.25` (not `0.25`) and should multiply instead of adding for the message. Like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How much is the bill payment? ");
double bill = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.println("What's the interest in this bill in per cent?");
double interest = 1 + (scan.nextDouble() / 100);

double interestCalculated = interest * bill;
System.out.println("Your interest is " + interestCalculated 
        + " dinheiros!\nSo the amount is " + bill
        + " + " + interest + "% dinheiros!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the statement:

```
System.out.println("Your interest is " + interestCalculated + 
   " dinheiros! \n So the amount is " + 
   bill + interestCalculated + " dinheiros!");
```

The argument to `System.out.println` is a bunch of literals and variables connected by `+` operators.  In the absence of any parentheses, the `+` operations are simply evaluated in left-to-right order, as if the statement had been written:

```
String $T1 = "Your interest is " + interestCalculated;
String $T2 = $T1 + " dinheiros! \n So the amount is ";
String $T3 = $T2 + bill;                   // String + number = String
String $T4 = $T3 + interestCalculated;     // String + number = String
String $T5 = $T4 + " dinheiros!";
System.out.println($T5);
```

What you wanted, of course, was to have `bill` and `interestCalculated` added together and that sum then incorporated into the overall string result, something more like this:

```
String $T1 = "Your interest is " + interestCalculated;
String $T2 = $T1 + " dinheiros! \n So the amount is ";
double $T3 = bill + interestCalculated;     // number + number = number
String $T4 = $T2 + $T3;                     // String + number = String
String $T5 = $T4 + " dinheiros!";
System.out.println($T5);
```

One way to force that order of evaluation is to add parentheses around `bill + interestCalculated`:

```
System.out.println("Your interest is " + interestCalculated + " dinheiros! \n So the amount is " + (bill + interestCalculated) + " dinheiros!");
```

Another alternative is to calculate the total in a separate variable and use that variable in the string expression:

```
double totalAmount = bill + interestCalculated;
System.out.println("Your interest is " + interestCalculated + " dinheiros! \n So the amount is " + totalAmount + " dinheiros!");
```

There's also a third option which you might like even better:

```
System.out.printf(
    "Your interest is %.2f dinheiros! %n So the amount is %.2f dineheiros!%n", 
    interestCalculated, 
    bill + interestCalculated);
```

Read more about `printf` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)